# Stateful Processing using mapGroupsWithState - output same key multiple times

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

I am using Spark Structured Streaming for my use case. My use case needs stateful processing. My Use case is below. I am using mapGroupswithStae, however the problem arises when within a batch the same customer comes twice, it randomly picks one customer Id and ignores the other.

e.g.

Customer Id, Ts
123, 09/03/2020T15:20:28.989Z-05:00
123, 09/03/2020T15:26:48.989Z-05:00

Expected O/p
Customer Id, Flg, Ts
123, I, 09/03/2020T15:20:28.989Z-05:00
123, U, 09/03/2020T15:26:48.989Z-05:00

Actual O/p
Customer Id, Flg, Ts
123, I, 09/03/2020T15:26:28.989Z-05:00

if the Customer Id is new then Tag the Customer Id as Create, perform transformation and write to Topic
if the Customer Id exists then Tag the Customer Id as Update, perform transformation and write to Topic

```
case class CustIdStatus (var CustId: String, var existsFlag: String, var Ts: String)
var df:Dataset[String] = spark.readStream.format("kafka").option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", bootStrapServer).option("subscribe", Topic).option("startingOffsets", autooffset).load().selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING) as value").as[String]
df.map(processsData)
.groupByKey(_.CustId.toString())
.mapGroupsWithState(GroupStateTimeout.NoTimeout()) (
isCustExists)
.writeStream
.format("console")
.option("truncate", false)
.option("checkpointLocation", "/tmp/output/checkpoint")
.outputMode("update")

def isCustExists (CustId:String, inputs:Iterator[InptObj], state:GroupState[CustIdStatus]):CustIdStatus = 
{
var newval:CustIdStatus = if (state.exists) CustIdStatus(state.get.CustId,"Y",state.get.Ts) else PtyIdStatus(CustId,"N","")
state.update(newval) 
newval
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to exchange `mapGroupWithState` with the more flexible `flatMapGroupsWithState`.

`flatMapGroupsWithState` is a generalization of `mapGroupWithState` and overcomes some of its limitation you are facing:

- The return type is an iteration, instead of a single object
- It takes another parameter, called the *operator output mode*, that defines whether the output records are new record that can be appended (`OutputMode.Append`) or updated key/value records (`OutputMode.Update`).

Comment: Thanks Mike for the response, but even with flatMapGroupswithState, though i get both the records for the same Customer Id, the output is not as expected , the Flg is I for both the cases, for one case it should be I and other case it should be U                     
Expected O/p Customer Id, Flg, Ts 123, I, 09/03/2020T15:20:28.989Z-05:00 123, U, 09/03/2020T15:26:48.989Z-05:00

Actual O/p Customer Id, Flg, Ts 123, I, 09/03/2020T15:20:28.989Z-05:00 123, I, 09/03/2020T15:26:48.989Z-05:00